# Access database from a differet host in django

Tags: mysql, django, host

I have a django site and I need to access data from another database which is in another host. how do I connect it and even if i connect, how do I access that table from this database, without having the table's data in the `models.py`? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Django ORM, you can use Django's built-in [multi-database support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/). To create the models.py file, you can use the [inspectdb management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb).

If you don't need the ORM, you can connect still specify the additional database in your settings, but [only perform raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly). You need to get the right connection for your additional database:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['my_db_alias'].cursor()
```

Comment: I use the username and the password for the respective hosts but I get an error as access denied

Comment: It says access is denied for the host from which I am accessing

Comment: Maybe your MySQL authentication config does not allow access from the host(s) that run your Django application. If you want to rule out configuration issues, try the mysql CLI from the django host

Comment: But how can I use mysql CLI from my django app? I want the database to be accessed when user requests

Comment: You can use the mysql cli from the django application server, to verify that the connection works. If it does work, the problem ("access denied") is with the django config, if it doesn't work, the problem is on the mysql side (or wrong username/password)

Comment: Ya the problem is the mysql side